# plot graph using if else statement in given vector matlab

Tags: matlab

i cant get the correct graph from the given vectors. i dont know whether i did it correct or not since i'm new to matlab.

```
beta=3;
gamma=1/beta;
BLq=15000;
SBLq=30000;
w1=1/4;
w2=3/4;
BLqsd=((w1*BLq)+(w2*SBLq));
B=1000000000;
C=1;
A=BLqsd/(B*C);

alpha=[0.1 0.2 0.3 0.4 0.5 1 2 3 4 5]
APqsd=alpha*A;
currentAPqsd=0.00002625;
P=beta* currentAPqsd;
O=gamma* currentAPqsd;
    if APqsd>=P
        APqsd=P;
    else if APqsd<=O
        APqsd=O;
    end
plot(alpha,APqsd,'-ro');

end
```

Comment: Code dumping and expecting us to figure out what's wrong doesn't really help us, nor is it the purpose of this website.  What do you **expect** this code to do?  What outputs are you getting?  What is the expected output?  What is wrong with the output?  Answer those and we'll be in a better position to help you.  Right now, all it looks like is a bunch of code that I don't even know works as you're not describing what it's supposed to do.

Comment: I dont know whether how i write the if else in the for loop is correct or not because i only can get 1 value.if you copy paste it to matlab,you will understand

Comment: The above code assumes that `alpha` is defined, then you're redefining it again in your `for `loop.  Is `alpha` supposed to be a vector?  The code doesn't declare `alpha` anywhere until the `for` loop happens, but you are using it before then.

Comment: i already updated my code. supposedly i will get a horizontal graph, but i got a proportional one. i think the if else statement is still not working

Comment: What output do you expect and what output you are getting? Upload your figure and attach a link to it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is basically a wild guess, but I'm assuming that you want to take your `APqsd` vector and check each element to see if it satisfies a Boolean condition, then replace the values from different vectors.  If I am interpreting what you want correctly, what you want is this:

```
%// Your code
alpha=[0.1 0.2 0.3 0.4 0.5 1 2 3 4 5];
APqsd=alpha*A;
currentAPqsd=0.00002625;
P=beta*currentAPqsd;
O=gamma*currentAPqsd;

%// Modified code
APqsd(APqsd >= P) = P(APqsd >= P);
APqsd(APqsd <= O) = O(APqsd <= O);

plot(alpha,APqsd,'-ro');
```

Basically, you want to check any values in `APqsd` are `>=` to the corresponding values in `P`.  If they are, then replace those values with the corresponding locations of `P`.  Similarly, you do the same check for `O`, but it's `<=`.  Once you're done you have your plot.

You can avoid using `if/else` and a `for` loop by just using logical indexing.

Comment: thanks for the answer.it is what ive been looking for.but what if the currentAPqsd is also in vector?

Comment: @Logitech - If it's a vector, then that will depend on what you want to do with that vector.  Would you select those values in `APqsd` where if **any one** of those values are greater than any value in `currentAPqsd`, these would qualify?  Going to vectors is ambiguous so you need to properly define what happens.  I can't answer that until you give me more details.

Comment: If the currentAPqsd is a vector,that makes P and O is also in vectors.so,i need to compare each element in APqsd with each element in P and O following sequence.then the graph is plotted.hope u understand.it takes me time to write in english